# Can I use Haskell's stack to compile and run _only_ the tests?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

When I run a `stack test` or a `stack test <package>:<test-suite>` then the output looks something like:

```
package: configure (lib + exe + test)
package: build (lib + exe + test)
package: copy/register
package: test (suite: tests)
```

And it ends up basically compiling all my changes twice: once for the exe or lib and a second time for the test.

What I would like is a command like `stack test --test-only` that would produce something like:

```
package: configure (test)
package: build (test)
package: copy/register
package: test (suite: tests)
```

I have already looked through the available command line flags and stack documentation. I have also attempted a google search to see if anyone has talked about something similar.

So my questions are:
1. What is the best currently available way to compile and run *only* the tests? My best guess on this one is to try putting the tests in a separate cabal package.
2. Is there some reason why stack doesn't or couldn't do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have made some experiments using `stack build <pkgname>:test:<testsuite>` and found nothing really pleasing when you have all your app/src/main in one <strike>directory</strike> cabal-project.

Now I did not investigate if this is an issue due to stack using `Cabal` as a library or whether this is a stack issue.

here are a few issues that might be related

- [Turning on test coverage rebuilds all packages #1940](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1940)
- [stack ghci foo:test:bar uses library dependencies unless --test is passed #1845](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1845)
- [Allow stack test to skip certain test suites #1659](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1659)
- [How to specify a subset of tests to run? #2519](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2519)
- ["stack test " does not run tests? #1961](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1961)

But I guess you'd have to file a bug if noone provides a better answer.

---

A possible but quite ugly solution (in my opinion) is to split test-suite, app and library into separate cabal projects - here is the example folder structure I used for testing.

```
myproject
├── stackapp            
│   ├── app             
│   │   └── Main.hs     
│   ├── ChangeLog.md    
│   ├── LICENSE         
│   ├── Setup.hs        
│   └── stackapp.cabal  
├── stacksrc            
│   ├── ChangeLog.md    
│   ├── LICENSE         
│   ├── Setup.hs        
│   ├── src             
│   │   └── Lib.hs      
│   └── stacksrc.cabal  
├── stacktest           
│   ├── ChangeLog.md    
│   ├── LICENSE         
│   ├── Setup.hs        
│   ├── src             
│   ├── stacktest.cabal 
│   └── tst             
│       └── Spec.hs     
└── stack.yaml
```

> ### stack.yaml
>
> ```
> resolver: lts-7.3
>
> packages:
> - './stacksrc'
> - './stacktest'
> - './stackapp'
> extra-deps: []
> flags: {}
> extra-package-dbs: []
> ```

Note that you need to include a "dummy" library section in order to make it compile, cabal is picky about cabal files that have neither lib nor exe part.

> ### stacktest.cabal
>
> ```
> ...
> library
>   -- dummy
>   build-depends:       base >=4.9 && <4.10
>   hs-source-dirs:      src
>   default-language:    Haskell2010
>
> test-suite tests
>   type:          exitcode-stdio-1.0
>   main-is:       Spec.hs
>   hs-source-dirs: tst
>   build-depends: base
>                , stacksrc
>                , hspec
>                , hspec-expectations-pretty-diff
>
>   default-language: Haskell2010
> ```

Then you can modify tests and run `stack stacktests:test:tests` without rebuilding the lib and/or the app part, but stack is intelligent enough designed to rebuild the lib part if you change it before you run the tests.

### UPDATE

For future reference here is a link to the opened ticket:

### [To use stack to compile and run *only* the tests #2710](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2710)

Comment: Well, that is the same conclusion I came to. I guess I'll open an issue on stack.

Comment: [here on github](https://github.com/epsilonhalbe/stack-tests--tests-only-example) is the source code for the example I have tested.